# Template page that replaces content according to routes/navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have ten pages that feature a different product. Lets say I want each page layout to be identical, so that the only visual pieces that would change when navigating between these pages is the content (the product image(s), text, etc.). Rather than actually having those 10 pages. I want to have 1 page as a template, and upon navigating products that template is used but renders different content. This content would be static, placed within the app code, not stored in the database. I'm looking for ideas/scenarios/cool & simple ways to accomplish this.

With the current setup, the static pages and routes to them already exist, so i'm attempting to accomplish this without changing up the routing for lots of reasons not worth mentioning. One way I know (and tried) would be to `provide` content from a product page and `yield` the content in a rendered template partial. This works but I just wanted to see if i could get other ideas from the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view part will be almost the same as with regular ActiveRecord+controller+view, you only have to replace the 'model' and controller layers to acomplish that.

Something like:

```
# controller code
MY_SEMI_STATIC_DATA=[{text:'txt', img:'image.jpg'}, {text:'', image:''}]
def show
  id = params[:id].to_i
  unless id >= 0 && id < MY_SEMI_STATIC_DATA.size
     raise 'not found'
  end
  @product = MY_SEMI_STATIC_DATA[id]
end
```

View:

```
<p><%= @product[:text] %></p>
```

And so on.

But it's very likely that in the nearest future you'll actually need a real model, db and so on.

Comment: Cool man. as for your last comment, yeah totally i agree. Unfortunately, I'm not aloud to make that (obvious) call (yet). The handcuffs are on. I've never handled anything this way before so its kind of weird to me. how could i render larger text? like, instead of having paragraphs of text in the controller?

Comment: You can go a 'make what databases were some 50-years ago'-way: manage files youself, for example have a json-file per object and load these in controller.

Comment: @user3127502 Are you not allowed even a sqlite?

Comment: we have a sql database setup for things (MySQL), i just can't touch it at the moment.